# Extract unlisted element from HTML in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html

I have some HTML file. I want to extract from here an unordered list. I have class name for this unordered list. And I am trying the following code:

```
soup =BeautifulSoup(HTML(open('dtaa.html').read()).__html__())
soup.find("ul",{"class":"name of class"})
```

dtaa.html is my file
This gives me nothing. This unordered list is inside  2 division. Maybe this is the problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can read the HTML file like this:

```
with open("dtaa.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, 'html.parser')
    
soup.find("ul", attrs={"class":"name of class"})
```

You could also try another parser, like:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "html5lib")
```

Documentation:

- [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#making-the-soup)
- [Reading & Writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: Thank you.Actually, I am working on google collaborator,that why I am open this way